# What is SPFx and why do we need this?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I know this is a generic question but I think there are many people out there who are novice in SPFx. I decided to learn this by following [This MSDN](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview). Can someone help me to understand

1. npm & yeoman?
2. Client side web part and Add-ins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: This is a generic question and no: it can't be answered completely within a forum post. There are loads of sites describing what it is and how to handle. If the MSDN texts don't fit perhaps those on github.com do? Discussing about SPFx needs to understand client-side programming in general on SP.

The same with further information on package manager like npm. Where to start here? Specific questions on the tools or in examples could be given. But not a general introduction in these techniques. This is the task of portals like npmjs.com or yeoman.io.

I would suggest to learn about all this step by step and by using those tools in your development system.